# How to Copy or mount files from docker volume file system to another container during run time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have copied a directory to docker volume space (/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name) using shutil.copytree from a path during run time.

```
shutil.copytree(env["directoy_files"], volume_path, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Now I would like to use above created volume in another container , and that container starts  using docker-compose  up command( run time only).

I have tried configuring compose file, expecting to mount in the started container. like below

```
 volumes:
      - my_volume:/etc/sampledata/:ro

volumes:
  my_volume:
    external: true
```

I can see files under /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name> , but couldn't find mounted in container.
Do we have some other way ?

Comment: You seem to be looking around inside Docker's internal filesystem space.  Ignore the `/var/lib/docker` directory: what created the volume in the first place?  (There can be a number of complexities around sharing files between containers, can you avoid this use case entirely?)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docker documentation on storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/), you should not directly modify the files in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`:

> Volumes are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is managed by Docker (/var/lib/docker/volumes/ on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem. Volumes are the best way to persist data in Docker.

Instead, you could let the volume be created through your `docker-compose.yml` and then use `docker cp` to copy the files to the path in the container (`/etc/sampledata/`). Alternatively, if you want to keep the "read-only" part, you could create a temporary container to copy the files, as described in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: cp doesn't possible between the docker host path(/var/lib/docker/volumes/) to another container

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not possible"? Do you encounter a specific error message? Other than that, you should not mess with the files in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` at all (as stated in the docs). It would be better move the files somewhere else.